# shared List<READING_ONLY_OBJECT> between threads: whitin a single thread is it safe to instantiate a list referenced to the same elements?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

We have this shared list, where "MyObject" represents a class **whose objects can't be modified after creation**:

```
List<MyObject> fooList;
```

When .add or .remove methods (which are the only things that can alter fooList) are called on fooList, fooList gets locked (Monitor.TryEnter...)

Each thread may do this while accessing it, while also locking fooList:

```
foreach (MyObject o in fooList)
{
    myList.Add(o);
}

foreach (MyObject o in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

Is it correct to assume that the locks are present only to make sure that fooList won't have any .add or .remove methods being called while a foreach iteration is in progress (hence invalidating it)?

In other words, if fooList was immutable from the start of the program, would it be safe to remove the locks?

Answer (score 1):

If `fooList` is indeed never modified after creation then there is no need for locks when you are reading values from it.  This includes using `foreach` over it.

If indeed `fooList` is never modified after creating then why not use `ReadOnlyCollection<Foo>` instead of `List<Foo>`.  This is a much more declarative and enforceable method of creating a list that doesn't change.  It would protect you from future accidental mutations of the list

Comment: Ok, I may have expressed myself poorly (not a native english here...) but I said "if fooList was immutable..." just to make the preceeding sentence more clear by asserting -possibly- the same thing in another fashion. Indeed locks are present, I was asking if the reason for which they are present is, as I think, only related to the possibility that .add or .remove methods are called during foreach iteration of the same list in another thread. Any further clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @CarloArnaboldi if Add or Remove methods are called, in htis thread or another, then the list is *not* immutable.  It would be very much a mutable value.  In that case you would need locks around the Adds, Removes and foreach calls.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, so you're saying that with my constraints this code is fine, right?

Comment: @CarloArnaboldi yes, so long as you lock on every access it will be fine.